# Can't seem to get my bootstrap grid/flex-boxes right

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and I'm trying to build a website for a client but I can't seem to get the grid to behave/expand as I want it to.

Here's a rough sketch of what I'm trying to achieve.

**Desktop Layout Sketch:**

[image: Screenshot Desktop Layout Sketch]

**Mobile Layout Sketch:**

[image: Screenshot Mobile Layout Sketch]

Here's a code snippet that I currently have that works on Desktop sizes but completly breaks down when the size goes mobile.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <h1 class="main-cap">Your Caption. Goes Here.</h1>
      <div class="d-flex main-desc flex-grow-0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus in nisl
        tempor, porttitor quam eu, lacinia nibh. Etiam
        interdum est magna, vel ullamcorper arcu
        dignissim sit amet. Nullam commodo elementum
        felis, id congue dui facilisis sit amet. </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm hidden-xs">
      <img src="assets/vectors/graphic.svg" class="img-fluid graphic-50px" alt="Engineering Graphic">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 style="padding-left: 30px;">
        <button type="button" class="learn-more btn btn-outline-primary btn-block btn-lg">
             Learn more
          <i class="material-icons arrow-right">keyboard_arrow_right</i>
        </button>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="socials col-xs-6"></div>
      <div class="email-form col-xs-6"></div>
  </div>
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: there is no col-xs-* is Bootstrap 4.. which version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code had tags and double quotes missing... to get the effect you want, you'd have to insert (either "the image" or "the description & buttons") twice and toggle it at the appropriate breakpoint...

code **snippet** below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
      <h1 class="main-cap">Your Caption. Goes Here.</h1>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 d-block d-sm-block d-md-none" style='border:1px solid pink'>
        <img src="https://www.akberiqbal.com/Jumbo.jpg" class="img-fluid graphic-50px" alt="Engineering Graphic">
      </div>
      <div class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus in nisl tempor, porttitor quam eu, lacinia nibh. Etiam interdum est magna, vel ullamcorper arcu dignissim sit amet. Nullam commodo elementum felis, id congue dui facilisis sit amet.
      </div>

      <button type="button" class="learn-more btn btn-primary ">
             Learn more
          <i class="material-icons arrow-right">keyboard_arrow_right</i>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 d-none d-sm-none d-md-block" style='border:1px solid red'>
      <img src="https://www.akberiqbal.com/Jumbo.jpg" class="img-fluid graphic-50px" alt="Engineering Graphic">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```